# Mysqli SUM(row count *20)

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

I've searched high and low for the answer to help with this one and have only managed to confuse myself further.

What I need is probably quite simple:
$row2 is basically the row COUNT of 'agent_name' AND 'office' who belongs to a particular group defined in another table, this functions as expected, I now need $paygtotal to display the SUM of that count *20

I managed to create the complex JOIN to establish the true COUNT and now I'm stuck on the simple SUM()

If only it was as simple as $paygtyotal = [$row2[0] *20]

```
$paygcount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enabled_boards WHERE  agent_name='$paygagent' AND office='$paygoffice' ";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $paygcount) or die (mysqli_error());
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 
mysqli_free_result($query);

**$paygtotal = ???**

$paygList.='<div id="paygA" class="fluid">' . $paygagent . '</div>
            <div id="paygO" class="fluid">' . $paygoffice . ' </div>
            <div id="paygC" class="fluid center">' . $row2[0] . '</div>
            <div id="paygT" class="fluid center">£ ' . $paygtotal . ' </div>';

}
}else{
$paygList="<p>!! ERROR !!.</p>";
}
```

Comment: What do you want to SUM? Just `$paygtyotal = $row2[0] * 20;` is not what you want?

Comment: HaHaHa, I did say it was simple didn't I, sometimes you just try to look far too deep into something that is staring you in the face, Thanks Honza can you put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I want to receive points for such simple thing. Glad I helped. And also I don't think your question is useful to anyone else, so no need to answer. No offense :-)

Comment: Ok, none taken but I do feel like a bit of a numpty now :) maybe I should delete it, but then again to be honest I'd have been glad of seeing it last night. Have a great day and cheers for the help.

Comment: No need to feel numpty, everyone's been there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` function:

```
$paygcount = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM enabled_boards 
    WHERE agent_name='$paygagent' AND office='$paygoffice' 
    GROUP BY enabled_boards.id
";
```